# Android Object Animator speed returning wrong value on some devices?

Tags: android, application-settings, objectanimator

I'm trying to get the speed of the animator from developer options using below code

```
final float animatorSpeed;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            animatorSpeed = Settings.Global.getFloat(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
                    0.0f);
        } else {
            animatorSpeed = Settings.System.getFloat(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
     0.0f);
    }
```

But its returning wrong result as speed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: wrong result? means what? what values are you getting?

Comment: @pskink  animator speed is 1.0 but it returning as 0.

Comment: what is stored in `Settings.System` ? or you are getting the values from `Settings.Global` ?

Comment: @pskink as of api 16 the Settings values are moved to Settings.Global and prior to that it was Settings.System...so as of now I'm getting from Settings.Global

Comment: and what is in `Settings.System`?

Comment: @pskink System settings, containing miscellaneous system preferences.  This
table holds simple name/value pairs.  There are convenience
functions for accessing individual settings entries.

Comment: and what is in `Settings.System`? what if you use them instead of `Settings.Global`?

Comment: @pskink I understood what you trying to say.Internally its the same value from Global Settings :-) . But my question is why is I'm getting wrong result even I tried on Global Settings

Comment: @pskink  I have tried both individually but the resul is the same

Comment: change the value in developer options to `1.5` or `2` or whatever, run your app, change it to `1` again, run your app, then read `ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE` documentation

Comment: offcourse not. I have tried that before asking this question :-) .In some devices its not giving proper result I have tried in varied devices.

Comment: 0... that was the question.